# Docker keeps crashing after migrating Linux server, error "status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT"

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, crash, docker-engine

I migrated my vServer to another one (very similar product, same host, new vServer has bigger SSD and more CPU cores). I cloned the old file system to the new server with rsync, adapted some settings like grub and ip/hosts entries. Everything is running without problems like on the old server before.

BUT: Docker seems to crash every few days.

This is the journalctl log:

```
Jun 10 20:02:03 vserv systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jun 10 20:02:03 vserv systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 10 20:02:03 vserv systemd[1]: docker.service: Consumed 26min 1.607s CPU time.
Jun 10 20:02:06 vserv systemd[1]: docker.service: Consumed 26min 1.617s CPU time.


Jun 14 11:57:52 vserv systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jun 14 11:57:52 vserv systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 14 11:57:52 vserv systemd[1]: docker.service: Consumed 20min 37.316s CPU time.
Jun 14 11:57:55 vserv systemd[1]: docker.service: Consumed 20min 37.321s CPU time.
```

I am running about 8 docker containers. I never experienced crashes on the old server. I googled for the error code but found nothing of help.

The problem is, that after docker crashes it restarts, but my container do not restart (docker ps shows not entries, I have to start all containers again manually with docker-compose).

What can I do to find out why docker crashes? Can I make the journalctl log e.g. more verbose?

```
OS:
Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Linux vserv 5.10.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-1 (2023-05-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
```